# Querying from app_controller without model loading

Tags: model, controller, cakephp-1.3

In the `AppController` I have several functions that uses the database. some for complex queries between unrelated models.

The one way I know to do it, is by loading a model and using it for the queries.

Is there a way to do it without loading a model?
Is there a way to use the `AppModel` for that?

#### Update

What I need it for is: some information should be available in every view (through an element) and it is composed from several tables, a "wide" join query.
In order to get it i have to load a model to memory and query through it.

But, since I don't need a certain model, I need to randomly select a model to load. not the best programming practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute queries over the current data source with

```
$this->query();
```

as the AppModel extends Model where the query() function is defined.
Take a look at the [documentation for query()](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelquery).

Comment: i think i need to explain myself better, i want to do it from within the app_controller, using(if necessary) appmodel

Comment: What do you need to do exactly? Maybe we could  help you more here if you explain exactly what you want to achieve.